# crystal reports 8 - set location dynamically in vb6

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have a VB6 front end, SQL Server 2005 as the back end and Crystal Reports 8.5 for reports.

I need to set the location at run time in my application as I have 2 databases.  My problem is that when I change database, but the location remain the same.  It will be great if anyone can help me out.  Thanks in advance for your time, and here is my code.

```
Private Sub prin_Click()
With CrystalReport1
    .Connect = MDI1.txtcn --> this is my connection info "driver={sql server};server=server;database=database;uid=user;pwd=password"        
    .DiscardSavedData = True
    .Action = 1
    .PrintReport
End With
```

Comment: +1 for clarity. welcome to SO.

Comment: For my own knowledge, what CR library are you using? CRAXDDRT.dll? CRAXDRT.dll?

Comment: hi Bobby well am not sure as i am somewhat new to crystal report.I have just insert the crystal report control from component in vb6.Where can i find these dll's.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Try some code like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSetLocations_Click()
    Dim CrxApp As New CRAXDRT.Application
    Dim CrxRep As CRAXDRT.Report
    Dim CrxSubRep As CRAXDRT.Report

    Dim strReport As String
    Dim i As Integer, ii As Integer

    strReport = "[Path to report file]"
    Set CrxRep = CrxApp.OpenReport(strReport)

    SetReportLocation CrxRep

    For i = 1 To CrxRep.Sections.Count
        For ii = 1 To CrxRep.Sections(i).ReportObjects.Count
            If CrxRep.Sections(i).ReportObjects(ii).Kind = crSubreportObject Then
                Set CrxSubRep = CrxRep.OpenSubreport(CrxRep.Sections(i).ReportObjects(ii).SubreportName)
                SetReportLocation CrxSubRep
            End If
        Next ii
    Next

    'open your report in the report viewer

    Set CrxApp = Nothing
    Set CrxRep = Nothing
    Set CrxSubRep = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub SetReportLocation(ByRef RepObj As CRAXDRT.Report)
    Dim CrxDDF As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable
    Dim CP As CRAXDRT.ConnectionProperties

    For Each CrxDDF In RepObj.Database.Tables
        Set CP = CrxDDF.ConnectionProperties
        CP.DeleteAll
        CP.Add "Connection String", "[Your connection string goes here]"
    Next

    Set CrxDDF = Nothing
    Set CP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With CR
     .ReportFileName = App.Path + "\Labsen2.rpt"
     .SelectionFormula = "{PersonalCalendar.PersonalCalendarDate}>= Date(" & Year(DTPicker1) & "," & Month(DTPicker1) & "," & Day(DTPicker1) & ") and {PersonalCalendar.PersonalCalendarDate}<=date(" & Year(DTPicker2) & "," & Month(DTPicker2) & "," & Day(DTPicker2) & ") and {Department.DepartmentName}= '" & Combo1.Text & "'"
     .Formulas(0) = "tglAwal = '" & DTPicker1.Value & "'"
     .Formulas(1) = "tglAkhir = '" & DTPicker2.Value & "'"
     .Password = Chr(10) & "ithITtECH"
     .RetrieveDataFiles
     .WindowState = crptMaximized
     .Action = 1
 End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the connection string like this:

`DSN=server;UID=database;PWD=password;DSQ=user`

The meanings of `DSN`, `UID`, `DSQ` are counter-intuitive, they are overloaded by Crystal.

Also check you have no subreports whose `Connect` properties would need to be similarly changed.

Comment: Hi and Thanks for your reply.I've put it like you say but now am getting message: run-time error '20599' cannot open sql server.my connection string like this:crystalreport1.Connect = "DSN=datapro1;UID=sal_mil;PWD=ss;DSQ=sa" where datapro1 is my servername and sal_mil my database.Any idea?thanks again for your time and reply.

Comment: Common problem is that the Server name and database name are saved in the crystal report.  What I have done to solve this is the create a Crystalreport Object in VB6 code and set the connection string to the correct server and database and then  set the reportsource to a query matching the existing crystal SQL but without specifying the database name ...  SELECT * FROM MyTable instead of SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable.  I got my start in Development using MS Access so it was a big change when I worked with Crystal.  Crystal 10 is much better if you can upgrade.

Comment: hi and thank you for your reply.My problem is how to change the database location in crystal report at run time in vb6.If you got a sample code it'll be great

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the recordset to your report? In this way you will be able to get data from any supported (i mean VB6 can connect to) databases dynamically, you can even merge data from multiple databases, your report will require the data(recordset) only and report will be created with Data Field Definition.